# Weekly data with BatchGetSymbols (package in R)

Tags: r

I would like to download weekly stock prices for some companies by using BatchGetSymbols package in R. 
In order to download the data you need to specify a few parameters like : first.date / last.date / freq.data and etc. The problem I faced is the following: the exact day of the week for the weekly data is not consistent and depends on the year and month.

Some examples:

1)

```
first.date <- '2015-01-02' # this date is Friday
last.date <-  Sys.Date()
freq.data <- 'weekly'
```

If I start from '2015-01-02'(Friday) the next data point is '2015-01-08'(Thursday) and starting from this point, all subsequent days are Thursdays.

2)

```
first.date <- '2010-01-08' # this date is Friday
last.date <-  Sys.Date()
freq.data <- 'weekly'
```

If I start from '2010-01-08'(Friday) the next data point is '2010-01-15'(Friday) in this case everything works as expected

3)

```
first.date <- '2014-01-10' # this date is Friday
last.date <-  Sys.Date()
freq.data <- 'weekly'
```

If I start from '2014-01-10'(Friday) the next data point is '2014-01-15'(Wednesday) and starting from this point, all subsequent days are Wednesdays.

Assuming you always specify first.date as Friday, depending on the year and month, the next and all subsequent days can be any day of the week (Monday-Friday).

What I am looking for is the code which provides weekly data based on the day of the week (if the first day is Friday then all subsequent days have to be Friday as well.

Here is my code:

```
# set dates
first.date <- '2014-01-10'
last.date <-  Sys.Date()
freq.data <- 'weekly'


# set tickers
tickers <- c('GE')  

l.out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                         first.date = first.date,
                         last.date = last.date, 
                         freq.data = freq.data,
                         cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                  'BGS_Cache') ) # cache in tempdir()

# select stock prices 
stocks <- l.out$df.tickers
```

I hope someone can help me:) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `seq`:

```
first.date <- as.Date("2014-01-10")
last.date <- Sys.Date()
seq(from=first.date, to=last.date, by="week")
```

This will return a vector of dates all with the same weekday.